# Good Eclipse plugin testing tool

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, testing, eclipse-plugin, automated-tests

We wrote several Eclipse plugins to allow us to debug the company's hardware and firmware.
I'm looking for a good tool that will automate GUI testing of the plugins.
I read about the Eclipse Unit tests but I'm looking for a more complex scenarios that also tests integration between the different plugins.
Freeware\open source is preferable if it will answer our needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [WindowTester](https://code.google.com/p/windowtester/) from Instansiations/Google. Google bought Instansiations in summer 2010 and then made this product free (and in December 2010 it's open source). This is a commercial quality automated test tool. It generates nice JUnit test cases from your recorded session.

Answer (score 2):

You definetely should try [Xored Q7](http://www.xored.com/products/q7/) for functional and UI testing of Eclipse-based applications, which is available in either Professional or Community Edition. The last one is free.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding GUI testing, have you seen [SWTBot](https://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/)? It may not be sophisticated enough for you, but it may be worth looking at.

I've had this proof of concept code sitting in the repository for a while waiting until the GUI in the project to be stable enough for it to be worth writing high level tests.

Hope some of this answer helps!

```
public class TestExampleGUI
{
public static Shell shell ;
public static Display testDisplay;
public boolean buttonClicked = false;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    testDisplay = new Display();
    testDisplay.beep();
    shell = new Shell(testDisplay);
    Button button = new Button(shell, 0);
    button.setText("Button");
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Default Pressed");

        }

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Pressed");
            buttonClicked = true;

        }

    });


    shell.setText("Test");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setSize(800,900);
    shell.open();

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception
{

}

@Test
public void testExampleGUI()
{
    SWTWorkbenchBot bot = new SWTWorkbenchBot();

    // click on a button with the given text
    bot.button("Button").click();
    assertTrue(buttonClicked);

}
}
```